# Make every button in application conform to subclass

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create a [pulse animation](https://materializecss.com/pulse.html) on any tap of a tappable object (so `UITextField`, `UIButton`, etc.) I can add the animation manually to every object, but since I'm applying this to a large codebase this will add a massive amount of code. So I was trying to find a way to apply a function universally to all objects of these type in the app.

So far I've created extensions on `UIView` such as:

```
func addPulseOnTouch() {
        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector(self.addPulseSelector))
        gesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        self.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }

    @objc func addPulseSelector(sender : UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        pulseAnimation(gesture: sender) // creates pulse animation
    }
```

Which creates a gesture recognizer, and it works for the most part (barring UITextFields, for some reason it blocks the selection still). However I'm running into many issues looping through all buttons, textfields, etc in a `UIViewController`. Currently I'm using this extension:

```
func addPulseToSubviews() {
        let allowedTypes = [UIButton.self, UIBarButtonItem.self, UISegmentedControl.self, UITableViewCell.self, UIControl.self]

        for view in self.subviewsRecursive() { // retrieves all subviews for the main view
            let viewType = type(of: view)
            for type in allowedTypes {
                if type == viewType { view.addPulseOnTouch() }
            }
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't recognize items inside `UITableView`s. So my question is if there is a way to

1) Apply the current extensions in a way that I can reach every item without individually setting `buttonName.addPulseOnTouch()`

or

2) Create a subclass that all buttons (etc) can conform to without manually setting the subclass for every single object in the application

Comment: Conceptually, the problem is that `if type == viewType` should be `if type is viewType`. A table view cell is unlikely to be an actual UITableViewCell, but it will surely be a subclass of a UITableViewCell.

Comment: But more largely the problem is that "tappable" is too broad. You can't go adding a tap gesture recognizer to things that already receive taps in some other way; you'll break them.

Comment: @matt That's a good point about the `is` vs `==`. I hadn't considered that, but for some reason I don't think that is allowed in this context. Changing only that value gives the error `Use of undeclared type 'viewType'`. I also agree that adding a gesture recognizer on everything isn't the best idea, however I'm not sure what else to do besides adding in button actions, rowSelected, didBeginEditing, etc functions for every single object nearly.

Comment: Well, I can certainly tell you how to find every instance of every subclass of a list of view classes. But I don't see how that's going to help you. Also there's the problem that every time the user scrolls, all table view cells get replaced with new views. So you could wind up in serious trouble doing this sort of thing. You should put a tap gesture on the _table_ and go from there, if anything.